# Error 100002 (Security Error - Security header is not valid)

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using **paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby** for Rails. For the sandbox environment, it uses https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ as the endpoint.

I am getting the following error when issuing a simple Mass Pay request:

`[#<PayPal::SDK::Merchant::DataTypes::ErrorType:0x007f2ff0ae2280 @ShortMessage="Security error", @LongMessage="Security header is not valid", @ErrorCode="10002", @SeverityCode="Error">]`

After verifying that my SOAP API credentials were correct, I tried switching to certificate-based credentials with no luck, revoked the certificate creds, re-issued signature-based ones, and updated them in my config. I am still getting the same error.

Here is my config for the development environment. I've already verified that the ENV variables are passing correctly.

```
# Mode can be 'live' or 'sandbox'
mode: sandbox

# Credentials for Classic APIs
app_id: ENV['api_cred_a']

username: ENV['api_cred_u']
password: ENV['api_cred_p']
signature: ENV['api_cred_s']
sandbox_email_address: ENV['api_cred_e']
```

Again, I'm using the correct endpoint, and I'm using the same username, password, and signature listed in my PayPal business profile. I'm also using the testing App ID.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the default test username, password, and signature that came with the SDK, and I no longer get that error. Perhaps the business profile API creds only work in the live environment.

From [pp_MSI_Jenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533169/pp-msi-jenn):

> If you are in the sandbox environment, you must use Sandbox account
>   API Signature credentials. If you are pointed to the live environment
>   then you can use your Live PayPal Account API Signature Credentials.

Comment: If you are in the sandbox environment, you must use Sandbox account API Signature credentials. If you are pointed to the live environment then you can use your Live PayPal Account API Signature Credentials.

Comment: Thanks! I've added that to the answer, since it answers the question